# Query Multilayer in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2, odm

I have a mongoDB application running on symfony2.2 framework.

The Database design is as follows.

Table

```
User,City,State

1 user belongs to one city.
1 city belongs to one state.
```

now I need to query all the users who belong to state A.

This is what i tried but with no result.

```
$response = $dm->getRepository('DataBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('city.state.$id')->equals(new \MongoId('123123asd123dqa4'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Any Ideas?

[EDIT]

```
 class User
    {
       /**
         * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="City", mappedBy="users")
         */
        protected $city;

 // getters and setters
}


class City
{
   /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="State")
     */
    protected $state;

  /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User", inversedBy="state")
     */
    protected $users;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your doc looks like, your current explanation is lacking

Comment: @Sammaye i have added the document code.

Comment: Hmm that should work, can you show us a document from the mongo console that your query should get?

Comment: db.user.find({ "city.state.$id": ObjectId("51a5ebb8085c97d40c596610") })     @Sammaye this is the query fired to the database but there is no response.

Comment: Yeah but can you show us one of the documents from the databae that is supposed to match?